# How do I check environment variables for my specific user in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, environment-variables

I did a few google searches on how to use environment variables in python. When I try to use `os.environ.get('token')` I get `None` returned. I can only assume it's because 'token' is in my user variables and not my system ones. I don't have admin permissions on my machine. How would I fix this/use environment variables for my user?
Variables: (ignore the french)    [image: my user variables]

Answer (score 2):

Have you set this variable after you have started your python terminal. Have you tried restarting your python terminal I have tried setting local variable in my windows OS, the starting a python terminal and can access the local variable fine

[image]

The documentation for `os.environ` mentions this......
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

> A mapping object representing the string environment. For example,
> environ['HOME'] is the pathname of your home directory (on some
> platforms), and is equivalent to getenv("HOME") in C.
>
> This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported,
> typically during Python startup as part of processing site.py. Changes
> to the environment made after this time are not reflected in
> os.environ, except for changes made by modifying os.environ directly.

So any changes to variables made outside of your code will not be reflected in your os.environ mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions [here](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5#:%7E:text=To%20set%20and%20get%20environment%20variables%20in%20Python%20you%20can,Get%20environment%20variables%20USER%20%3D%20os.) using the  `python-decouple` package.

They also explain there why you get `None`

Comment: Alright, let me try it. By the way, I know it returns None because the variable dosen't exist